# gtk2 menus are slow

Tags: gnome, gtk-2

My PC runs ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell. Some time ago after an upgrade the menus in gtk2 apps became slow, i.e. there's a delay while opening the context menu in synaptic, claws-mail, etc. gtk2 apps. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your problem might relate to corruption of your font or icon cache, for example see here:

https://www.marksanborn.net/linux/speed-up-the-gnome-menu-and-fix-the-annoying-icon-delay/